# 'current_user' undefined in rails_admin with clearance

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-admin, clearance

I've been using rails_admin v0.7.0 with the clearance gem successfully up this point. I tried to update rails_admin to v1.0 today, but am getting an undefined variable or method error for `current_user`. In v0.7.0 it appears that `RailsAdmin::MainController` inherits from `ApplicationController`, whereas in v1.0 it inherits directly from `ActionController::Base`, which would explain `current_user` is now undefined (I believe `current_user` is defined in `ApplicationController` with the clearance gem). However, since I'm not finding anyone else with this problem, I'm thinking I must be missing something.

I wasn't the one who set up clearance on this app, but I don't think we're doing anything non-standard with it that would affect this. `Clearance::Controller` is included in `ApplicationController`. No special definition of `current_user`.

config/initializers/rails_admin.rb

```
RailsAdmin.config do |config|

  # Popular gems integration

  ## Clearance
  config.authorize_with do |controller|
    unless current_user.admin?
      redirect_to(
        main_app.root_path,
        alert: "You are not permitted to view this page"
      )
    end
  end

  config.current_user_method { current_user }
end
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You are correct that Rails Admin inherits from `::ActionController::Base` by default, and that is what is causing your issue. Fortunately, the fix is simple. Add `config.parent_controller = "::ApplicationController"` to `config/initializers/rails_admin.rb`:

```
RailsAdmin.config do |config|

  ## == Clearance ==
  config.parent_controller = "::ApplicationController"

  config.authorize_with do |controller|
    unless current_user && current_user.admin?
      redirect_to(
        main_app.root_path,
        alert: "You are not permitted to view this page"
      )
    end
  end

  # You actually don't need this line    
  # config.current_user_method { current_user }
end
```

I've created a [reference repo here](https://github.com/philtr/clearance-and-rails-admin) for comparison if you need it.

Comment: Thank you!! This line fixed it for me ```config.parent_controller = "::ApplicationController"``` I am using custom auth